# Update gitlab JDK to JDK17 (VM doesn't have internet connection)

Tags: java, ant, gitlab

I am using Gitlab to build a Java tool using `ant`

The tool requires JDK 17, but `ant` JDK version is 11, and I'm trying to change it.
So I tried a lot of solutions using a remote repository or remote download site, but after some tries I found out that the VM used to build the tool is not connected to internet (trying to ping google or my IP address doesn't work).

So I tried to upload in the same package with the tool source code the JDK 17 (`openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`) and install it there.
Here is the problem, I am not sure how to do this since I don't work with linux, but I tried almost everything on the internet.
Every of these commands are used in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, used for gitlab pipeline.

Here are some examples of what I've tried so far:

```
    - sudo cp /builds/project/openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm
    - sudo tar zxvf "/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz" -C /usr/lib/jvm
    - echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
    - echo "PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
    - echo "export JAVA_HOME" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
    - echo "export JRE_HOME" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
    - echo "export PATH" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
    - sudo cat /etc/profile
    - echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17" | sudo tee -a /.bashrc
    - echo "PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin" | sudo tee -a /.bashrc
    - echo "JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment"
    
    - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17
    - export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

After a lot of combinations of these commands the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config java` is still:

```
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But if I try `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java -version` it prints `17`.
What would be the solution of making the default Java version to be 17. (Also a solution for ant to use the JDK-17 without installing it would be great too, since I need the JDK-17 for `ant`)

Comment: Don’t you run in a docker image? Can you change the image?

Comment: `Using Docker executor with image organizationwebpage/ccp/vm:stable ...` this is what it says, so I guess you're right, but I don't know how I could change the image.

Comment: Is it an in-house image? Can you talk to those that made it?

Comment: I don't know what type of image it is, I don't know where I can see details about it, and for sure if it's not managed by someone in the team (and it's not) I can't reach them

Comment: Create a new image (possibly based on what you have) and push it to a repository gitlab trusts and then revise your gitlab yml

Comment: I understand. Anyway, I can't use it somewhere else, since I need to automate it to be build everytime on this repository (so using this image). So I am looking for a solution of using another JDK no matter what's the version installed by the image, and this could bring the advantage of not changing anything if they change JDK version in the feature. Also changing the JDK version in the image would not be a good idea since the same image is used by multiple projects. But thanks a lot, even if it doesn't solve the problem, it helps me to understand better how things work. Thanks again!

Comment: What you are suggesting is going to be done in each and every build.  That will be slow and require resources.   If all you need is Java 17 with ant, then why not find a docker image having that, and then switch to that?  You may want to use this opportunity to do local experiments and learn docker better because this will save you time.

Comment: I agree, this will be slower, but the build takes 2-3 minutes anyway, and for sure I don't know how I can use another image on the our company gitlab organization. For example, all my projects gitlab links looks like this: code.companyName.com. And I don't have access to any configuration

Comment: If you are in a company doing this there are persons responsible for ensuring these things work.  Now would be a good time to ask the person you answer and/or your team to how you should continue with this - adapt the current build or upgrade the image.     Also, why are you not getting any help with this task?!

Comment: It's pretty complicated. The team I'm working with is not technical at all. There were 3 guys before me taking care of all things (tools, projects, scripts and technical issues). I was replacing one of them since he was leaving. Now all left and I'm the only one. These projects are pretty complex so it's hard to get help from other teams, since they would have to spend some time on understanding these, so I'm just making my way through the problems xD. I've solved the problem, I will post the solution. I've just copied everything from JDK-17 over the folder of JDK-11 before using `ant`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
    - sudo cp jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm
    - sudo tar zxvf "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/lib/jvm
    - sudo \cp -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
    - sudo \cp -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
    - sudo \cp -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
    - sudo \cp -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17 /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11
    - sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java
    - sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javac
    - sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java 1
```

What I did here was to copy the JDK-17 content to all folders from `/usr/lib/jvm` folder. So even though the docker image uses JDK-11, I'm rewriting it using JDK-17 uploaded with the source code, and now the tool is built using JKD-17.
PS: I know this is slower and not professional, but in my case, it's easier and more convinient than trying to get help from those who setup the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already found a way to change the jdk on-the-go, you may really want to consider change the base image of your CI to save yourself a lot of time. This step will boost your CI speed. The steps to do that is fairly simple too.

1. Compose your own Dockerfile

This following is just a pesudo code. You may look into the description of [dockerfile builder](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

```
FROM your-original-image. This is what you have in your image tag in the gitlab-ci file.

COPY jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm
RUN sudo tar zxvf "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/lib/jvm \
    && sudo \cp -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 \
    && sudo \cp -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java \
    && sudo \cp -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 \
    && sudo \cp -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17 /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11 \
    && sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java \
    && sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javac \
    && sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java 1
```

2. Build the docker image

- If you are using docker hub, then you need to login to docker and get a dockerId which matches the dockerId in the snippet.
- If you are using a private repo like harbor or artifactory, you may need the permission to push to it.

```
docker build . -t dockerId/Name-of-your-image-you-want:latest
```

3. Upload the docker image using docker push

```
docker push dockerId/Name-of-your-image-you-want:latest
```

4. change the image tag in your gitlab-ci.yaml to `dockerId/Name-of-your-image-you-want:latest`

Comment: This was already proposed by someone in the comments of the question. There is the problem, the container is managed by another team, and they use it for multiple projects, so it's pretty hard to change these. Also I cannot create my own, since the deploy should be done only in this project... But thanks for the reply, this could help someone else who comes to thins question.